# How to pass Object array to unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, marshalling, unmanaged

I'm trying to pass an array of objects from C# to unmanaged C++, and nothing seems to work.

The compiler won't let me pretend the array is an IntPtr.  Casting the array to an IntPtr doesn't work.  I've tried to pass the address of pinned data, but this didn't work either.

I just need to pass a pointer to the beginning of the array, and this is turning out to be incredibly difficult.

Any suggestions or links?  Thanx!

Comment: How do you expect to see that array from unmanaged code (i.e. what will be the element type)?

Comment: I have (hopefully) the same object definition on both the C# and C++ sides.  The called function has a pointer to this type as the parameter.

Comment: You mean a C++ class definition? It doesn't work that way. In-memory layout of a CLR class is implementation-defined, you cannot match it from C++. What you can do is have the objects implement some interface, and provide an unmanaged definition of that interface on unmanaged size, and then let P/Invoke marshal the array.

Comment: Would it be easier if I changed the CLR class to a struct?  (Either would work in the program.)

Comment: If your struct does not itself contain any object references, and if what you want is really an array-of-structs rather than array-of-references (because the latter is what you actually have with array of objects), then, yes, it should all just work.

Comment: Hmm... the class/struct has strings in it, which are references.  How should these be handled?

Comment: Thanks Pavel, the struct worked.  A string was automatically being converted to ASCII bytes, so I preceded it (in the struct definition) with: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]  and that converted it to the wide-character string I needed.

Answer (score 2):

What finally worked:

1. Passing an array of structs instead of an array of objects (references).
2. Putting "[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]" just before the struct definition.
3. Putting "[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]" before the string (in the struct definition) to cause the string to appear as a wide-character string on the C++ side.
4. Declaring an array of structs for the argument in the DllImport declaration: "VariableObject[] varObj".
5. Declaring a pointer to the class as the parameter on the C++ side.  (The C++ class mirrors the C# struct.): "VariableObject* varObj".

Answer (score 1):

Can you cast to a void pointer?  Be sure the array of objects is pinned.

Comment: I tried:

VariableObject[] varObj = new VariableObject[numVarObjects];
GCHandle pinnedData = GCHandle.Alloc(varObj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = pinnedData.AddrOfPinnedObject();

The Alloc call results in: "Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.".

Comment: You cannot obtain a pointer to a managed type. An array of managed types is also a managed type, and an object reference is a managed type.

Answer (score 0):

In your C#/Managed method signature, mark the input parameter with **[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]**...

```
[DllImport(...)]
public void DoTask
    (
        ...,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] int[] results,
        ...
    );
```

Then call it as you did always. Also, inside the unmanaged code, you can modify this array. I suggest that you send in an extra int telling the unmanaged code what the size of the array is to prevent “array out of bound” modification.